# Why is $_POST array empty in PHP after an a request with post data

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, post

I make a post request to the the page getremote.php with post data but the $_POST array seems to be empty. Would be grateful if anyone can tell me what I've done wrong.

The javascript code to make the request is

```
var postdata = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n\nedits=" + this.createEditXMLtext(this.editXMLstruct);
 var xmlhttp;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
 else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
  dispmes("processing edits");
 xmlhttp.open("POST",userProfile.homeurl + "?remoteurl=" + userProfile.homeurl + "&cmdeditprofile&password=password",false);

 xmlhttp.send(postdata);

 var response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```

where this.createEditXMLtext(this.editXMLstruct) simply creates a string

I haven't had this problem before and don't seem to have the same solution as other people who have posted similar problems.
The php code at userProfile.homeurl + " is

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
 $query = '';                  
    foreach( $_POST as $key => $value ){ 
  $query .= "$key=$value&";
 }
 echo do_post_request($_GET['remoteurl'] . $qstring,$query);
```

but the string $query is always empty - I checked it by adding echo $query to the bottom of the file

Comment: Are you 100% sure `POST` is empty? What does a `print_r($_POST);` yield?

Comment: I guess that the Header information must be separated from the body with two \r\n and not only \n.
HTTP 1.1 specification:

generic-message = start-line
                          *(message-header CRLF)
                          CRLF
                          [ message-body ]
        start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line

CRLF = \r\n

Comment: You should certainly consider going to a javascript framework like jQuery, Dojo, or YUI to handle your AJAX requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value you pass to [send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send%28%29) should be the entire post body, and you've included a header in it. When that body reaches PHP, it will fail to parse it as encoded form data.

Instead, set the data type by calling [setRequestHeader()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29)

```
 //create the postdata, taking care over the encoding
 var postdata = "edits=" + encodeURI(this.createEditXMLtext(this.editXMLstruct));

 //let server know the encoding we used for the request body
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

 //and here we go 
 xmlhttp.send(postdata);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen it done this way, try setting your header separately from the POST body via [`XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#setRequestHeader%28%29), like this:

```
var postdata = "edits=" + this.createEditXMLtext(this.editXMLstruct);
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
dispmes("processing edits");
xmlhttp.open("POST", userProfile.homeurl + "?remoteurl=" + userProfile.homeurl + "&cmdeditprofile&password=password",false);
xmlhttp.send(postdata);
var response = xmlhttp.responseXML;
```