# AJAX: POSTed value arriving in $_GET

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following JavaScript code in the header of my page; note that I use POST:

```
function sendInput() {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://.../somefile.php?someInput=123', true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            alert('ready: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I call the function in body onload:

```
<body onload="sendInput();">
```

In the PHP file $_POST is empty. The value for someInput is found in $_GET.

Shouldn't an AJAX request done with POST arrive in $_POST?

Comment: You send nothing with `POST`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST from XMLHttp with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071544/post-from-xmlhttp-with-parameters)

Comment: You are confusing GET url params with the POST body params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using the url to form your variables is GET. In order to send via post you need to change your code like this:

```
    function sendInput() {
    var params = "someInput=123";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open('POST', 'http://.../lsomefile.php', true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
            alert('ready: ' + xmlhttp.responseText);
          }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You couldn't get any values in $_POST. because no values posted by you. Please refer the below for posting data to particular URL
[Send POST data using XMLHttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest)