# How to pass parameter to php while calling it from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am calling a PHP script from JavaScript. Whenever my function is called, I want to set `tag=image`. How can I do that?

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200) {
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("POST", theUrl, true); 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('storeImage.php');
```

The file storeImage.php looks like

```php
<?php
$img = $_POST['tag'];
 $folderPath = "C:/xampp/htdocs/";

    $image_parts = explode(";base64,", $img);
    $image_type_aux = explode("image/", $image_parts[0]);
    $image_type = $image_type_aux[1];

    $image_base64 = base64_decode($image_parts[1]);
    $fileName = 't' . '.jpeg';

    $file = $folderPath . $fileName;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_base64);

    print_r($fileName);
    $command = escapeshellcmd("python C:/xampp/htdocs/generate_graph.py");
    $output = shell_exec($command);
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: Well, you have `xmlHttp.open("GET"` and then `$_POST['tag'];` so first you need to decide whether you want to be making a POST request or a GET request and then use the same term on both sides.

Comment: i have updated my question.Now how can i do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST from XMLHttp with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7071544/post-from-xmlhttp-with-parameters)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713058/send-post-data-using-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 0):

There are **conflicts**,

1. In your `xmlHttpRequest` you are triggering a `GET` Request.
   But, In your `storeImage.php`, You are accessing `POST` data.
2. The `httpGetAsync` functions get 2 parameters `(theUrl, callback)`, But when you call the function, You only pass the url.

**Correct Example Code**

```js
function httpGetAsync(theUrl){
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
          alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl + "getData=hello", true); 
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

```php
<?php

  echo $_GET['getData'];

?>
```

**Please Take a tour**
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp

Comment: Yes You need to change it to `post`

Comment: i have tried with both get and post .but it is not working.i have uploaded my whole code.can you tell me where is the problem?